# Domain sharing on Google Drive disappears

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

We have a custom-built application that utilizes the Google Drive API. The client and I are on different domains but our Drive is enabled to allow sharing with other domains and I am the owner. We had an issue where the Domain sharing (Anyone at [domain] can find and edit/view) is disappearing and users can no longer access the Intranet.

I tried determining what is causing the issue and found the only way to remove an entire domain is if you turn Link Sharing OFF, or ON then OFF.

I can't figure out if there is a bug causing the disappearance, or if someone is changing the link sharing settings (for whatever reason). I also can not find a way to add the Domain sharing back for someone outside of my domain.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, if there is anything else that could make the Domain disappear, or if it is in fact because of the Link Sharing setting? Also, once a Domain disappears from the share list, is there a way to add it back? Please note I have also tried adding explicit edit rights to one of the users from the Domain and it still doesn't bring the "Anyone at [domain] option back". We can't do this for each user, it has to be a domain-wide setting.

To fix this, I have to recreate the folders so that they take the permission settings of the parent folder, which still has the "Anyone at [domain] can find and edit/view" and then I move the files into the new folder and everything is okay. However this seems to keep happening and is disrupting employees. It is also an issue because the share setting of the parent folder trickles down to all folders and there are different settings for each subfolder.

So I'm thinking to do the following:
If I go to Share > Advanced there is an option "Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people". This will ensure no one makes any changes they aren't supposed to but I haven't yet tested how it affects files in the folders and subfolders.

My second option is to ask the client to create a dev gmail account for us on their domain and I can recreate all the folders from their domain, so we won't have this cross-domain issue (our Domain share settings never disappear since I am the owner).

Please let me know if you've experienced this and found a better solution or if something else can be causing this.

Comment: Hi Sandra. Can I suggest you progress this through Google Support as it's not really a Drive SDK or StackOverflow-compliant issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I will do submit it through Google Support.